# Including URL encoded characters in regex for .htaccess file

Tags: regex, .htaccess, urlencode

I need to include URL encoded symbols in the regex for my `.htaccess` file for special characters in different languages.

I have the following which includes space characters `%20`:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([0-9a-zA-Z\s-]+)/?$ search.php?search=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

But I need to be able to include characters like `õ` which is `%C3%B5`.

Basically I need this to include any URL encoded character with a `%` character.

Comment: Use `^search/([^\/]+)/?$` to allow any characters but `/` in your `$1`.

Comment: Thanks a million. Put that in as an answer and I'll accept it straight away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `[^\/]` [**negated character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
^search/([^\/]+)/?$
```

It matches

- `^` - start of string
- `search/`  - a literal substring
- `([^\/]+)` - Capturing group 1 (the contents it matches are referred to with `$1`): any 1+ chars other than `/`
- `/?` - an optional `/`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code in your site root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?search=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

- You need to **turn off** `MultiViews` option because your `php` filename is same as the starting URI component. Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/search` is the URL then Apache will serve `/search.php`.
- `RewriteCond` is needed to make sure you don't match a directory named `search/` in your site root directory.